# How to trim strings based on values from another column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame like below:

df:

```
col1       col2 
ACDCAAAAA    4
CDACAAA      2
ADDCAAAAA    3
```

I need to trim col1 strings based corresponding col2 values like below:

dfout:

```
col1     col2 
ACDCA      4
CDACA      2
ADDCAA     3
```

I tried : `df['col1].str[:-(df['col2'])]` but getting NaN in output.

Does anyone know how to do that?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprhension with `zip`:

```
df['new'] = [a[:-b] for a, b in zip(df['col1'], df['col2'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

A regex option might be:

```py
df["col1"] = df["col1"].str.replace(r'.{' + df["col2"].astype(str) + r'}$', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.apply`:

```
In [2613]: df['col1'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['col1'][: x['col2'] + 1], 1)
```